# How to add edit project btn and show only in show action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How to add edit project button in application.html.erb and show only in show action?

projects_controller.rb

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav>
      <%= link_to 'Edit Project', edit_project_path(@project), class: 'btn'  %>
    </nav>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

error

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"projects", :id=>nil}):
  app/views/shared/_nav.html.erb:17:in `_app_views_shared__nav_html_erb__1271203285425734977_70214901149120'
  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:16:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___2967596751769284574_70214923607360'
```

Comment: Why are you adding the button on the application layout? Add it to the view in views/projects/show.html.erb. BTW next time post the error you're getting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define the `edit` action in your controller.

```
def edit
  @project = Project.find(parmas[:id])
end
```

Also, create a file under `app/views/projects/edit.html` as the controller will look for a corresponding view file.

Read up on [Action Controller](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html) from the rails guide to give you a better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want that there, you can check `controller_name` and `controller_action` in the view, so you can hide/show your button when you want to.

You can also access that info from the `params` hash.

With that the button won't show when `@project` isn't defined.

GL & HF.